# How to replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform or migrate to navigator.userAgentData

Tags: reactjs, navigator, stack-navigator

I'm facing the issue in my react js. When i fetch data from news Api key it is loading only in one page and next button is not working when I'm clicked to move next page. it is an unhandled issue. console is neat nothing at all no error in showing but on issue is come i don't  know its relevent to my problem or not and i don't know how to solve this issue. May be API request limit is ended. but i wait more than 14 hours but nothing happened. If anyone can know about it please help me. Next button is not working just but data is fetching on page but next button is not worked for next data

I want to make a application that fetch article. it is working data is fetching but i want to show next data is showing on second page . the logic of next button for showing data is write and it showing not any error but next button is not clicked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.